# Javascript Descending Timer with Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds

Tags: javascript, timer

I have searched all over internet a lot but could not find solution.

I want a timer with descending order with minutes, seconds and milliseconds. i.e. 05:59:999 -> 5 Minutes, 59 Seconds, 999 Milliseconds.

Below is my code which give me just minutes and seconds :

```
var countdownTimer = '';
var upgradeTime = 300; // total sec row from the table
var seconds = upgradeTime;

function timer() 
{
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML = pad(minutes) + " : " + pad(remainingSeconds);
    document.getElementById("timer1").style.border = "1px solid";
    document.getElementById("timer1").style.padding = "4px";
}

function pad(n) 
{
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
}

$('#acstart').on('click', function(e)   // Start the timer
{
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
});
```

I found fiddle with seconds and milliseconds here is the link :
http://jsfiddle.net/2cufprgL/1/

On completion of the timer I need to call other action.

Thanks

Comment: I'll see if I can make something from what you have so far.

Comment: you should not use setInterval but the date object for precise timers

Comment: My idea was to intergrate Momentjs

Comment: @Jacob I haven't used moment js never before

Comment: I will create something, and send you the code either on github or codesandbox

Comment: @gamerneskonge It seems like I need to use date object as per rv7 but Is it possible as per my requirements ?

Comment: @Jacob Huge thanks brother I have been searching all over the internet from last 2 days.

Comment: @rv7 It seems like I need to use date object. Is it possible to make descending timer as per my requirements ?

Comment: @SagarVirpara Of course it is possible

Comment: @AbanaClara What would be the approach to implement it ?

Comment: `const moment = require('moment');

const timer = () => {
  const current = moment().format('mm:ss:ms');
  const fiveMinuteEvent = moment()
    .add(5, 'minutes')
    .format('mm:ss:ms');
  const diffTime = fiveMinuteEvent - current;
  const duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds');

  console.log(current, 'CURRENT');
  console.log(fiveMinuteEvent, 'FIVEMINUTE');
  console.log(diffTime, 'DIFFTIME');
};
timer();`

Comment: Oh that looks bad in comments... lol. I will work on it more later its midnight here.

Comment: @Jacob Ohk No Problem I will wait for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fiddle you included, you only need to update the displayCount function to get the result you want.

```
function displayCount(count) {
    let res = Math.floor(count / 1000);
    let milliseconds = count.toString().substr(-3);
    let seconds = res % 60;
    let minutes = (res - seconds) / 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =
        minutes + ' min ' + seconds + ' s ' + milliseconds + ' ms';
}
```

Note that your fiddle has the correct approach to countdown, everytime the timer ticks it measures the actual time left it doesn't assume that the timer was 'on time'.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this clean. But I did follow through using your code. I did change it to recursive `setTimeout()` though.

What I did is call the interval faster than 1000ms, set a specific `speed` variable and then properly decrement `seconds` while checking for a flag when `seconds` becomes 0, this flag then calls `stopTimer()`.

```js
var countdownTimer = '';
var upgradeTime = 3; // total sec row from the table
var seconds = upgradeTime;
var milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
var speed = 50; //interval speed

function timer() 
{
    milliseconds    = (seconds * 1000) - speed; //decrement based on speed
    seconds         = milliseconds / 1000; //get new value for seconds
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = (seconds % 60).toFixed(3);
    
    if(seconds <= 0){ stopTimer(); return; } //sets a flag here for final call
    
    document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML = pad(minutes) + " : " + pad(remainingSeconds);
    document.getElementById("timer1").style.border = "1px solid";
    document.getElementById("timer1").style.padding = "4px";

    setTimeout('timer()', speed);
}

function stopTimer(){
    clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
    console.log("IT HAS BEEN DONE");
    document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML = "00 : 00.000"
}

function pad(n) 
{
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
}

clearTimeout(countdownTimer)
countdownTimer = setTimeout('timer()', speed);
```

```html
<div id="timer1"></div>
```

Comment: It works great but I will wait for efficient solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something that sorta works logically right now. It's a tad unstable because of what I was trying to do.  https://codesandbox.io/s/8xr1kx8r68

Momentjs with Countdown library - its a little outdated and unmaintained but looks like it does something like what you want. 
https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown
http://countdownjs.org/readme.html